# Calling getParams() in Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to achieve the below getParams() in Magento2?

```
$params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can directly call inside phtml file like below,

```
$blockObject= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Namespace\Vendor\Block\YourBlock');

$params = $blockObject->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Answer (score 14):

In controllers and blocks you have direct access to the request object:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams()
```

Anywhere else, you have to add `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` as constructor parameter if it is not there yet, and assign it to `$this->request`. Then you can use

```
$this->request->getParams()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Fetch All Posted data on a controller in a variable**

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

**Use a helper on phtml**

```
$this->helper('\Helloworld\CustomModule\Helper\Data')->getCustomdata($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

will get you the post data

If you want to get specific param

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('something');
```

Responsible class is `\Magento\Backend\App\Action`

If you want get the values into phtml, one possibility is Use registry. for example.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
)
{
    $this->registry     = $registry;

}

$this->registry->register('test_var', 'this is a test!');

echo $this->registry->registry('test_var');
```

Register the values in controller and create a function in your block(PHTML file using) by using the block ($block) pass the data into template.

Comment: ok..and how to call the $helper = Mage::helper("myhelperclass"); in my phtml